# Selenium (Java) - Access to Network tab in Chrome Developer tool

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to get data from Headers in Network by searching a file name like this:
[image]

I tried LogEntries but it seems like I only can get data from console.
How can I achive this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this:

```
List<WebElement> performanceEntries = (List<WebElement>) ((ChromeDriver) driver).executeScript("return window.performance.getEntries();");
for (WebElement entry : performanceEntries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getAttribute("name"));
```

Comment: I tried it but I got this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')